# Customizable heat map for strings

Tags: python, pandas, heatmap

I am writing to you since I did not find a satisfactory answer to my question. Specifically I have a pandas data frame containing string characters for each variable. It is made as follows:

```
Own AUSTRIA.  Own BELGIUM. 

"-1.3"          "-0.34"
"-0.43"         "-1.89**"
"-1.2**"        "-4.5"
"-1.9"          "-2.3"
"-2**"          "-6.1**"
"-.7"           "-0.3"
"-0.06"         "-7.2**"
...             ...
"-1.1**"        "-10.34"
```

What my goal is, is to produce an heatmap where terms having the `"**"` charachter are coloured in red, while others in blue (other color are fine). I know that heatmaps are based on the values' input but if I try to rescale the values with `"**"` either also other values are taken for I have too set too high (low) values soo that heat map understands which values need to be coloured.

Thank you,

Federico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a 'heatmap dataframe', use large values for red, low values for blue.

```
heatmap = df.copy()
heatmap = heatmap.apply(lambda x: 255 if '**' in x else 0)
```

You can of course use any range you want, like [0, 1], [0, 255], [-1, 1].